# Ошибка 0 () при передаче с сервера json-объекта

Tags: reactjs, сервер, flask

Использую связку Flask+React. Имеется запрос на сервер, который должен возвращать json-объект (информация о структуре графа) для отрисовки во фронтенде (с помощью Cytoscape.js).

У меня прописан `print()` объекта на серверной стороне сразу до того как он будет возвращен

У меня прописан `console.log()` возвращенного с сервера объекта сразу же как он будет получен.

Проблема в том, что при количестве узлов примерно больше 150 (выяснил эмпирически) cервер все делает нормально, `print()` срабатывает и выводит что нужно, но клиент не получает ничего, процесс просто повисает, написав в консоль
`GET http://запрос 0 ()`, `console.log()` даже не выполняется. Что это за `0 ()` такое?

С графами меньше 150 узлов все нормально. Но непонятнее всего то, что проблема проявляется только если обращаться к серверу через внешний ip. Если запускаться во внутренней сети, то все работает корректно при любых размерах графа

Comment: Вариантов много. Уточню - с внешнего IP работает при меньшем количестве узлов?

Comment: Если нет - CORS. Если да - проверь сам запрос, возможно из-за большого объёма данных ответ разбивается на chunks